# A unique continuous linear map

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be Hilbert space with ortonormal basis $\lbrace e_n\rbrace _{n=1}^{\infty}$. Suppose that elements $h_n (n=1,2,...)$ of $\mathbb{H}$ are given such that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}||h_n||^2 < \infty$. 
Show that there is a unique continuous linear map $T:\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H}$ such that $Te_n = h_n (n=1,2,...)$.

I am wondering how to prove this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x \in \mathbb{H}$ we have

$x= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}<x,e_n>e_n$.

Then define

$Tx= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}<x,e_n>h_n$

and show that $T$ is well defined, linear and continuous and that $te_n=h_n$ for all $n$.

Then show that if $S$ is another linear and continuous operator on $\mathbb{H}$ sucht that $Se_n=h_n$ for all $n$ , then $T=S$ on $\mathbb{H}$.